# check all function is checking all checkboxes instead of specified id

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried using class names, id's as well as just the name of the checkboxes but everytime I do a checkall function, it checks ALL boxes on page regardless of id,name,class. I even made it so that the checkbox id/class has a counter at the end of it and having the jquery function counting and using the counter to find the checkbox based on current count but it still causes ALL checkboxes to be checked.

jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#check_all_batch').change(function() {
                var batch_add_checkboxes = $('input[name="batch_add[]"]').length;
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    for (var autoinc = 1; autoinc <= batch_add_checkboxes; autoinc++) {
                        $("#batch_add_"+autoinc).prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
                        console.log(autoinc);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var autoinc = 1; autoinc <= batch_add_checkboxes; autoinc++) {
                        $("#batch_add_"+autoinc).prop('checked',false);
                        console.log(autoinc);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

html:

```
<!-- at the top of the form, outside of foreach loop -->
<input type="checkbox" id="check_all_batch"> 
<!-- two checkboxes inside of foreach -->
<input type="checkbox" name="reimbursement[]" value="1"> // this is the one that keeps checking itself as well as the below checkboxes when this has nothing in common with the below checkbox
<input type="checkbox" id="batch_add_'.$expenses_count.'" name="batch_add[]" value="1">
```

I have a php foreach loop with counter starting from 1 and goes up to 13 in this current scenario based on results

browser console with log output shows the correct numbers going up:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

any help would be great. im sure it's something really dumb that i'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in a much simpler manner:

```
$('#check_all_batch').on( 'change', function() {
    $( 'input[type="checkbox"][name="batch_add[]"]').prop("checked", $(this).prop( 'checked'));

});
```

Comment: Hello David, I tried what you suggested and same result, still checks ALL boxes rather than only the batch_add[] boxes. I'll have to do some more testing, there has to be something else in the background that I am not seeing. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: found the culprit, code buried in the footer... so dumb.
                     `$(".table th input:checkbox").click(function () {
    $checks = $(this).closest(".table").find("tbody input:checkbox");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $checks.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
     $checks.prop("checked", false);
    }    
   });`